# Jenkins client certificate authentication

Tags: jenkins, apache2, jetty

You could use Apache with Jenkins to use client certificates for authentication, but is there a less bulky way that is just as simple on Windows or RHEL? Perhaps, customizing the Jenkins code is an option, since it says it already runs in a Jetty servlet? A way to do this in Hudson itself?

With Apache Web Server, I was fighting with some plugins, like Selenium related plugins. Also, I noticed more issues connecting to slaves when using a proxy despite using the tunnel option. Leaner and meaner would be nice.